# Solving system of linear congruences (3 pairs)

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

So we have the following:

$$2x \equiv 3\pmod {5} \\ 3x \equiv 4\pmod {7} \\ 5x \equiv 7\pmod {11}$$

which reduces to:

$$x \equiv 4\pmod {5} \\ x \equiv 6\pmod {7} \\ x \equiv 8\pmod {11}$$

Now the confusion begins here. At this point, I choose the first two pairs of congruences and equate them, giving:

$$ 5k+4= 7l +6 \\ \\$$

But I'm not sure what to do past this point. I know in essence I need to solve this and pair this new equation with the last one and re-do the steps. It's just past this point I don't know how to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step in simplification of the congruences is correct. Now use the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to solve the system.

Comment: You might also find these links useful, especially if you are new to the Chinese Remainder Theorem. http://mathsforall.co.uk/userfiles/Chinese%20Remainder%20Theorem(1).pdf                                     http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/chinese.shtml

Answer (score 0):

For solving the system of linear congruence, we need to use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
2 x \equiv 3 & (\bmod 5) \\
3 x \equiv 4 & (\bmod 7) \\
5 x \equiv 7 & (\bmod 11)
\end{array}\right.
\Leftrightarrow \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x \equiv 4 & (\bmod 5) \\
x \equiv 6 & (\bmod 7) \\
x \equiv 8 & (\bmod 11)
\end{array}\right. $$
First of all, I am going to solve the following system of linear congruence for $A, B$ and $C$
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
7 \times 11 A \equiv 4 & (\bmod 5) \\
5 \times 11B \equiv 6 & (\bmod 7) \\
5 \times 7 C \equiv 8 & (\bmod 11)
\end{array}\right. \Leftrightarrow \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
77 A \equiv 4 & (\bmod 5) \\
55 B \equiv 6 & (\bmod 7) \\
35 C \equiv 8 & (\bmod 11)
\end{array}\right. $$
$$\Leftrightarrow\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
2 A \equiv 4 & (\bmod 5) \\
-B \equiv 6 & (\bmod 7) \\
2 C=8 & (\bmod 11)
\end{array}\right. \Leftrightarrow \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
A \equiv 2 & (\bmod 5) \\
B \equiv 1 & (\bmod 7) \\
C \equiv 4 & (\bmod 11)
\end{array}\right. $$
Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, the integer solutions for the system are

$$385k+77\times 2+55\times 1+35\times 444$$

$\text{i.e. }\boxed{385k+349,}\tag*{} $

where $k\in \mathbb Z$.

:|D Wish you enjoy my solution! Your suggestions, comments and alternate solutions are warmly welcome!